# Deploying on remote JBoss 6.x with Cargo

Tags: deployment, ant, jboss, cargo

I'm trying to setup an Ant Target to perform a remote deploy on a JBoss 6.x server, using Cargo.

Here is my target description:

```
<target name="deploy" depends="install-cargo,make-war">
    <input message="Enter username for deployment..."
                addproperty="deploy.username" />
    <input message="Enter password for ${deploy.username}..."
                addproperty="deploy.password" >
        <handler type="secure" />
    </input>
    <cargo containerId="jboss6x" action="redeploy" type="remote">
        <configuration type="runtime">
            <property name="cargo.hostname" value="${deploy.host}" />
            <property name="cargo.servlet.port" value="${deploy.host}" />
            <property name="cargo.remote.username" value="${deploy.username}" />
            <property name="cargo.remote.password" value="${deploy.password}" />
            <deployable type="war" file="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.war">
                <property name="context" value="${ant.project.name}" />
            </deployable>
        </configuration>
</cargo>
```

Every jar inside [jboss.home]/client and [jboss.home]/lib is inside cargo.tasks classpath but when i try to execute the Target I get this error:

```
 javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: impossibile trovare la classe LoginModule: org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule
```

That is Java cannot find class org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule (by the way: this class is located inside jbosssx.jar in [jboss.home]/lib).

Am I missing some jar? Do I need to configure something for jaas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no one who tried an automated deployment with ant on JBoss 6? How did you do that?

Comment: at the expense of reviving a dead thread, i'm hitting the same issue.. I'm hoping that you had fixed this and that you remember the solution 3 years later. this is driving me up the wall for the past 2 days. no amount jar updates, classpath updates seem to fix the problem. any pointers?